# Online payments service with the best NodeJS library/wrapper

Tags: javascript, node.js, service, payment

I am looking for an online payments solution like Chargify, Braintree or something else. The context is I am using NodeJS and for now just want to test how to work with online payments in development mode. So, main aspects for me is not how these services work in real-world apps, but more which of them has the most convenient connector library/wrapper written for NodeJS.

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the list of modules provided in Node's Github repository: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-payment-gateways , there you can find Braintree module and also paynode which supports multiple payment gateways.

Comment: As of '15 that page is deprecated!